# Process.on function called on every iteration of loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, unhandled-exception

I have following two questions;

1. My loop will run for three-time, and produced error (unhandledRejection) for one time and no errors for the 2nd and 3rd. But the results show that process.on called on every iteration (means three times). Why ? process.on should be called only for when unhandledRejection error occurs, not for others ??? What is wrong with my code?
2. If i want to access my member variables of 'tx' (i.e. tx.n, tx.to, etc.) in process.on function and want to save them..., how could I do that?

Here is my code

```
const abcWeb = require('abc-web');
const abcWeb = new abcWeb('http://testnet-jsonrpc.abc-xyz.org:12537');

const abTx = require('abc-transaction');
var n = 12;
var gp = 10;
var gl = 21000;
var to = '5989d50787787b7e7';
var value = 70;
var limit = 3;
var i=1;
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

  try{
const tx = new abTx({
    n: n,
    gp: gp,
    gl:gl , 
    to: to, 
    value:value ,
  });

    abTx.sign(Buffer.from('8f2016c58e898238dd5b4e00', 'hex'));
    abcWeb.abx.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex'));
    console.log(abTx);

  } catch (exception) {
    var message = exception.message;
    console.log(message);
  }

  // n +=1;

}

process.on('unhandledRejection', error  => {
  console.log("Rejected due to  ",error)
})
```

Output is

> Rejected due to   Error: Node error: {"code":
>   Rejected due to   Error: Node error: {"code":
>   Rejected due to   Error: Node error: {"code":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all using try...catch inside a loop will give you unexpected result for more reference look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32844818/why-i-need-to-avoid-using-try-catch-finally-inside-a-loop).

Now for your 1st query you should try following hack to get expected results,

Just Put your try...catch block in a function and call it instead.

```
for (i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    const tx = new abTx({
        n: n,
        gp: gp,
        gl:gl , 
        to: to, 
        value:value ,
    });
    myTryCatch(tx, abTx, abcWeb);
}


function myTryCatch(tx, abTx, abcWeb){
    try{
        abTx.sign(Buffer.from('8f2016c58e898238dd5b4e00', 'hex'));
        abcWeb.abx.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + tx.serialize().toString('hex'));
        console.log(abTx);

    } catch (exception) {
        var message = exception.message;
        console.log(message);
    }    
}
```